# How to exit from a script once a certain condition is met in a function, without executing further functions/further lines of the script in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a script in bash and I have some 15+ kubectl commands, after execution of each kubectl command, I need to check if echo $? is zero (or) not(which means it is successfully executed or not), if it is not zero, then I should exit from the script without executing the further lines/ further commands/further functions specified in the script. For this, I wrote a function, after every command I am calling this function to do the condition check of echo $? (for this function I am passing echo $? as an argument).

how to exit completely from the script once the echo $? !=0?

[image]

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not as a screen capture. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Are you aware that 0 means success?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but your script doesn't make much sense to me, i'll try to provide an answer to your question anyway.

In bash scripting exit code 0 means success, anything but that means an error with some numbers having a [special meaning](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF).

To achieve what you want to do you need this simple function to be executed after every kubectl command:

```
function check() {
    [ $? != 0 ] || exit 1
}

$command
check
```

Comment: The above code is not working as expected.

Comment: Mate if you want to get help you need to understand that you have to be more specific. What are you getting from your script? what is the expected output? Also try sharing your actual script and explaining where it's failing instead of posting a screenshot of some bogus script.